# GetBlob count for azure blob storage block file

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cost-calculation

I have uploaded a 6 GiB file into Azure Blob storage Hot Tier, as 4 MiB blocks.

When I Put the file, it will create (6000/4) PutBlock * 1 PutBlockList call. which is 1501 API calls.

However, when I try to download the file, does it make 1500 GetBlob calls or just one GetBlob (or any other API calls) ?

What all are the API calls that happen when I try to download a large file of 4 MiB block size and how many of those API calls contribute to the cost?

I am not able to find a conclusive reference to this question in the documentation.

Comment: Are you using any SDK to download the blob?

Comment: we are using Azure Storage Explorer https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/features/storage-explorer/#overview

We also use JS library https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs for programmatic access.

There are two kinds of users, some who use our cloud solution, others desktop-based access via Azure Storage Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are  using BlobClient.download() method in JS SDK @azure/storage-blob, the method will always try to download a blob with one request. If the file is large, it may meet error with the request, then it will retry to continue on downloading from the end offset of downloaded content from the last request.

Comment: Thank you, Is there any way to predict the number of requests the JS SDK would make to download a large file. I am trying to do cost computation per file.

Comment: It depends on network and service status, we don’t have an actual predict.